# To parse XML using XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the below XML. I want to retrieve the `item id` and `batters` when `topping id = '5002'`. Kindly help.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <items>
        <item id="0001" type="donut">
            <name>Cake</name>
            <ppu>0.55</ppu>
            <batters>
                <batter id="1001">Regular</batter>
                <batter id="1002">Chocolate</batter>
                <batter id="1003">Blueberry</batter>
                <batter id="1003">Devil's Food</batter>
            </batters>
            <topping id="5001">None</topping>
            <topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>
            <topping id="5005">Sugar</topping>
            <topping id="5007">Powdered Sugar</topping>
            <topping id="5006">Chocolate with Sprinkles</topping>
            <topping id="5003">Chocolate</topping>
            <topping id="5004">Maple</topping>
        </item>
    </items>
```

Here is my piece of code but I'm not able to retrieve the item ID and batters.

```
String expression1 = "/items/item/topping[@id='5002']";
NodeList nodeList1 = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression1).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < nodeList1.getLength(); i++) {
    Node nNode = nodeList1.item(i);

    System.out.println("\nCount :"+count);

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
    {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;   
        System.out.println("Item ID : "+ eElement.getAttribute("id"));
        //System.out.println("Item Name : "+ eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
                //System.out.println("Item PPU : "+ eElement.getElementsByTagName("ppu").item(0).getTextContent());
                //System.out.println("Item Batters : "+ eElement.getElementsByTagName("batters").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Item Topping : "+ eElement.getTextContent());
                count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Do you want `item id = 0001` and all the `batter` elements in your xpath result ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want `item id` and `batters` then you can use the following xpath :

`//topping[contains(@id,'5002')]/parent::* | //topping[contains(@id,'5002')]/preceding-sibling::*/batter`

Java code would be :

```
String expression1 = "//topping[contains(@id,'5002')]/parent::* | //topping[contains(@id,'5002')]/preceding-sibling::*/batter";

NodeList nodeList1 = (NodeList) xpath.compile(expression1).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < nodeList1.getLength(); i++) 
{
        Node nNode = (Node) nodeList1.item(i);

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
        {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;   
            if ( eElement.getNodeName().equals("item"))
            {
                System.out.println("Item ID : "+ eElement.getAttribute("id"));
            }
            else if ( eElement.getNodeName().equals("batter"))
            {
                System.out.println("Batter : " + eElement.getTextContent() );
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This expression helped me //item[topping[@id='5002']]